KafkaConnect: TimestampConverter for fields with custom date/time format
How do I add a custom date/time converter do correctly transform a custom date/time format, e.g. yyy-MM-dd?
I tried
"transforms": "TimestampConverter",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "string",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "startDate"

according to https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html.
My data contains a value field startDate in the yyyy-MM-dd format, as in
{
   ...
   "startDate": "2023-07-01"
}

However, even with above transform active, running KafkaConnect with this source data results in a strange "integer interpretation" of data fields, eg. above data record results in
{
   ...
   "startDate": 19539
}

I'm not sure if TimestampConverter is actually working and just wrongly configured or if it's not working at all and if so, how I would get it to work.
